# Compare 2 arrays and filter matched elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var array1 = ["AL", "CA", "IN "];
var array2 = ["AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "IN", "IN", "WI", "WY"];
```

My desired o/p:

```
["AL", "CA", "IN"]
```

2. 

```
var array1 = ["AL", "CA", "I"];
var array2 = ["AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "IN", "IN", "WI", "WY"];
```

My desired o/p:

```
["AL", "CA"]
```

I tried like this:

```
const intersection = array1.filter(element => array2.includes(element));
```

console.log(intersection)
But i am getting o/p : `["AL", "CA"]`. Can some one help me on this.

I want to compare 2 arrays and find the result with matched elements,I searched a lot but could not get a solution .please help me in advance.

Comment: Your actual output seems to match your expected output. What's exactly the problem? Is the extra space after `IN` tripping you up? Is that a typo?

Comment: in 1) `array1[2]` has a space at the end.

Comment: You have a space at the end of `"IN "`. If it is a typo, remove that. Or, you can use  `array2.includes(element.trim())`

Comment: I want to compare array1 with array 2 and want the o/p with matched elements Suppose:var array1 = ["AL", "CA", "IN "];   var array2 = ["AL", "AL", "CA", "CA", "IN", "IN", "WI", "WY"];  When i am comparing above 2 arrays i want 0/p :["AL", "CA", "IN "]  but getting  ["AL", "CA" ];

Comment: `"IN " === "IN"` is `false`, that's why you don't get matches. You have different strings. As adiga said, either remove the space from `"IN "` manually or `.trim()`.

Comment: i copied ur code and spend like 5 minutes and finally realized u have a mistake in ur array. "IN" and "IN " are different

Comment: Understood ThanK You Roby,VLAZ,adiga